# Node.js - Window.Location.Href Not Working

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to build a Puppeteer app that can be uploaded to a web server and receive parameters via the URL, but I can't seem find a way to get the current URL from my browser using Node. Right now I have a default server.js file created by Visual Studio which I modified to include code for getting the URL, but when I run the file I get an object promise error for window.location.href.

Here is the codeL

```
'use strict';
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    var url = window.location.href;
    res.end('Hello World\n' + url);
}).listen(port);
```

My goal is to be able to get the URL and then pass it to my Puppeteer script as a parameter when it is run. The above code should result in a url value of http://localhost:1337 which could then be modified to include any additional parameters by appending query strings.

Next I tried getting the URL outside of the createServer loop by appending the following:

```
var url = window.location.href;
document.write(url);
```

That causes the app to crash with no error message beyond failing to connect to the server.

This is my first Node.js application, so the concept of server side javascript is new to me.

Comment: There is no `window` object in nodejs.  That's something that exists in a browser, not in nodejs.

Comment: Within a nodejs request handler, you can use `req.url` to get the URL of the incoming request.

Comment: Also, your code references `purl` in `res.end('Hello World\n' + purl);`, but there is no such variable in the code you show.

Comment: There is also no `document` variable in nodejs.  You seem to be very confused about what code runs in your server and what code runs in a web page in the browser.  `document` and `window` work only inside a web page in a browser, not in nodejs.  Perhaps it would benefit you to read about how the http client/server architecture works and what code runs where (client and server are separate computers with separate code environments).

Comment: There has to be some way to get the URL and pass it to Puppeteer. How else do all the screenshot APIs built on Puppeteer get parameters from URLs?